# ImageMagick doesnt work under Debian. Missing libopenexr6 / libIlmImf which is missing from repository

Tags: linux, debian, imagemagick

I upgraded to Debian GNU/Linux 9.4 (stretch) , and now ImageMagick doesn't work.

`convert --version` gives this error:

```
convert: error while loading shared libraries: libIlmImf.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I try to install `libIlmImf.so.6` or `libopenexr6` with `sudo apt-get install` and I get this:

```
E: Unable to locate package libIlmImf
Package libopenexr6 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libopenexr6' has no installation candidate
```

I've reinstalled ImageMagick but no luck yet, any hints how to get ImageMagick back online working?

FWIW, the version of ImageMagick I installed was installed via `sudo apt-get install` like this:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Comment: @JakeGould using sudo  apt-get install imagemagick

Comment: In Debian stretch, imagemagick is a dummy package depending on imagemagick-6.q16, which is at this moment version 8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-11+deb9u5. Please show what versions of imagemagick and imagemagick-6.q16 you currently have installed (add this info to the question).

Answer (score 0):

Package `libopenexr6` is not available for Debian 9, so perhaps installing the `libopenexr22` package which is available for Debian 9 would solve your problem.

According to the package search page of Debian there are these packages:

```
- Package libopenexr22
stretch (oldoldstable) (libs): runtime files for the OpenEXR image library
2.2.0-11+deb9u4 [security]: amd64 arm64 armel armhf i386
2.2.0-11+b1: mips mips64el mipsel ppc64el s390x

- Package libopenexr23
buster (oldstable) (libs): runtime files for the OpenEXR image library
2.2.1-4.1+deb10u1: amd64 arm64 armel armhf i386 mips mips64el mipsel ppc64el s390x

- Package libopenexr24
sid (unstable) (libs): runtime files for the OpenEXR image library
2.3.0-6: amd64 arm64 armel armhf i386 mips64el mipsel ppc64el s390x
experimental (libs): runtime files for the OpenEXR image library
2.3.0-5 [debports]: powerpcspe

- Package libopenexr25
bullseye (stable) (libs): runtime files for the OpenEXR image library
2.5.4-2: amd64 arm64 armel armhf i386 mips64el mipsel ppc64el s390x
bookworm (testing) (libs): runtime files for the OpenEXR image library
2.5.4-2: amd64 arm64 armel armhf i386 mips64el mipsel ppc64el s390x
sid (unstable) (libs): runtime files for the OpenEXR image library
2.5.7-1: alpha amd64 arm64 armel armhf hppa i386 ia64 m68k mips64el mipsel ppc64 ppc64el riscv64 s390x sh4 sparc64 x32
```

(https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=libopenexr)

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.